# Find the flaw in the given proof.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, abelian-groups, fake-proofs

[image: The proof in question]

So, abstract algebra beginner here. The proof I have uploaded supposedly only works for abelian groups, although the actual theorem is true of all groups. Call me stupid, but I can't figure out why it wouldn't work even for nonabelian groups. I've tried hard and long, but I just can't figure it out. Not that I'm very good at abstract algebra anyway. So, could you please help me and tell me where the proof goes wrong? I'll be grateful.

Comment: @CaveJohnson The proof is supposed to prove the theorem for _all_ groups, but it supposedly only works for abelian groups. I can't understand why.

Comment: Why do you write the proof you uploaded "supposedly" works only for abelian groups? Where is that written, or where do you deduce that from?

Comment: It's given right after this proof as an exercise: "The proof given above is not generally correct. It is true only for abelian groups."

Comment: $\prod_{g\in G} xg=x^n \prod_{g\in G} g$ This step only works for abelian groups; If things don't commute you cannot pull $x$'s out there

Comment: @user160738 Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The crucial part of the proof is the rewriting at the bottom of the first page
$$ \prod_{s\in S_x} s = \prod_{g\in G} xg = x^n\prod_{g\in G} g = x^n \prod_{s\in S_x}s $$
The products here do not explain which *order* to multiply the elements of $S_x$ or $G$ in, so they are only even meaningful if we know the order doesn't matter -- that is, if the group is abelian.

Even if we fix a particular order of multiplication for the initial $\prod_{s\in S_x} s$, the *second* equals sign depends on moving all of the $x$s in the product out in front of all of the $g$s, which is only valid if the group is abelian, and the very point of the *third* equals sign is to rearrange the order of the elements to be multiplied, because we know that the $g$s and the $xg$s are the *same elements* but generally in a different order.

Comment: Ah, that's it! I wonder how I missed that. I'll have to work harder on my observation skills. Thanks a lot for your help!